# End the system operation in AWK that causes action to generate endlessly

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm monitoring a log file for a keyword that will trigger an email. The problem is the code is generating email endlessly. I'd like to receive only one email even if there are several lines of the same keyword.

I tried the following:

```
'{if(!seen[$1]++)print $1}'
```

but I don't know how or WHERE to apply it to the existing code:

```
tail -fn0 user | awk '/disconnect_tcp_conn/ { 
    system("mail -s \"Server is down\" mail@gmail.com </dev/null") 
    print "Server is Down"
```

The desired result is either end all emailing after the first sent email, or, end the emailing and monitoring after the first email is sent. I prefer to only end the emailing operation and continue monitoring but will except ending everything.

Comment: If you simply want to exit when the email is sent, the keyword for that is `exit`. The code you found prints unique occurrences in the first input field.

Comment: wrt `I prefer to only end the emailing operation and continue monitoring` - what would you be continuing monitoring **for** since you only ever do anything when that text is found and you only want to report when it is found the first time? Do you have other code testing for other things? Show us a real [mcve] to get the right answer.

Comment: @tripleee I think exit is the only way to go.

Comment: And i suppose you're right @Ed, no reason to continue the operation.

Comment: OK. It would of course be trivial to not exit and just not report that condition after the first occurrence if you had some purpose in mind but you can always ask a followup question later I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's another log message when the server comes back up, you can set a variable when you see the disconnect message, and clear it when you see the reconnect message.

```
tail -fn0 user | awk '
    !server_down && /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { 
        system("mail -s \"Server is down\" mail@gmail.com </dev/null") 
        print "Server is Down"
        server_down = 1 }
    server_down && /reconnect_tcp_conn/ {
        system("mail -s \"Server is up\" mail@gmail.com </dev/null") 
        print "Server is Up"
        server_down = 0 }'
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted and yet exceeds what I expected. Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't accept this as an answer as it's just a polish to what Barmar posted just to show an alternative implementation without redundancy:

```
awk '
    /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { report("down") }
    /reconnect_tcp_conn/  { report("up") }

    function report(curr_state,    msg) {
        if ( prev_state != curr_state ) {
            msg = "Server is " curr_state
            system("mail -s \047" msg "\047 mail@gmail.com </dev/null")
            print msg | "cat>&2"
            prev_state = curr_state
        }
    }
'
```